# Bootstrap collapse not working as expected

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I was trying to make disappear a text and replace it with another one and in the same time I've a flag that must change at each click but it changes only on the first click. My new text only appears and disappears on each click but the first text keeps in place and if I change it's class to "collapse" instead of "collapse in" it never appears. Here's my code :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#en").on("show.bs.collapse", function(){
    $(".flag").html('<a href="#en" data-toggle="collapse"><img src="img/france.jpg" alt="french"></img></a>');
  });
  $("#fr").on("hide.bs.collapse", function(){
    $(".flag").html('<a href="#en" data-toggle="collapse"><img src="img/US-GB-Flag.jpg" alt="english"></img></a>');
  });
});
```

```html
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <style>

      .container h1 {
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 50px;

      }
      .container {
        color: black;
        text-indent: 50px;
        font-size: 20px
      }
      .empty {
        height: 5%;
      }
      .jumbotron {
        background-color: transparent;
        text-align: right;
        transform: translateX(-20%)
      }
      .flag {
        text-align: right;
        height: 20%;
      }
      .flag img {
        width: 30%;
      }
      .pict {
        text-align: center;
      }
      .pict img {
        height: 30%;
      }
    </style>
 </head>
<body>
<div class="row">
  <div class="jumbotron col-md-8">
    <h1>Condor</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 flag" id="fr" >
    <a href="#en" data-toggle="collapse"><img src="img/US-GB-Flag.jpg" alt="english"></img></a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 pict"><img src="img/img1.png" alt="img1"></img></div>
  <div class="col-md-4 pict"><img src="img/img2.png" alt="img2"></img></div>
  <div class="col-md-4 pict"><img src="img/img3.png" alt="img3"></img></div>
</div>
<div class="empty"></div>
<div class="container collapse in" id="fr">
  <p>
    AZERTY AZERTY AZERTY AZERTY AZERTY AZERTY AZERTY AZERTY AZERTY AZERTY AZERTY AZERTY
</div>
<div class="container collapse" id="en">
  <p>
    QWERTY QWERTY QWERTY QWERTY QWERTY QWERTY QWERTY QWERTY QWERTY QWERTY QWERTY QWERTY
  </p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to hook up the event listeners on your newly added dom elements.

Comment: I made some little changes cause i had twice the same id which isn't a good idea so i changed this : `<div class="col-md-4 flag" id="fr" >` to this : `<div class="col-md-4 flag" id="lang" >` but now i know why the flag didn't changes back, it's cause the hide event for the id #fr never happens but no idea why. So i'm not sure that hooking up my new dom elements will change something. A little example could be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finnaly i achieved to do with adding a new event to force the toggle event so that the js looks like this :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#lang").click(function(){
    $("#fr").toggle();
    $("#en").toggle();
  });
  $("#en").on("show.bs.collapse", function(){
    $("#lang").html('<a href="#fr" data-toggle="collapse"><img src="img/france.jpg" alt="french"></img></a>');
  });
  $("#fr").on("hide.bs.collapse", function(){
    $("#lang").html('<a href="#en" data-toggle="collapse"><img src="img/US-GB-Flag.jpg" alt="english"></img></a>');
  });
});
```